# Dart make synchronous api call

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm learning flutter and I want to call an api which returns json. Because HttpClient methods are async and I don't want to deal with Future to build my material app, I've used the [sync.http](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/sync.http/sync.http-library.html) library but when I test the following code :

```dart
var result = Map();
try {
  final apiUri = Uri.parse('https://api.quotable.io/random');
  var request = SyncHttpClient.getUrl(apiUri);
  var response = request.close();
  var contents = response.toString();
  result = jsonDecode(contents);
}
on Exception {
  result['content'] = 'Could not contact host';
  result['author'] = 'None';
}
    return result;
```

I get the error :

> Unhandled exception:
> Unsupported operation: unsupported http response format

I think this means that the json format isn't supported by the library but I find this weird. Do you know how I  can call my api call synchronous ?

Comment: Any particular reason why you don't want to deal with Futures and async?

Comment: Because I don't really know how I can build the material app by calling a Future

Comment: use futurebuilder widget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about the `SyncHttp` client from the docs it looks like an internal client used by flutter or the flutter team. I could be wrong but either way its not a good choice for a UI to have sync `http` requests.

Flutter provides a `FutureBuilder` Widget which will allow you to use async methods in the `build` method.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: FutureBuilder(
        future: fetchData(), // Your API Call here
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return Text(''); // Your UI here
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text('Error');
          } else {
            return Text('Loading');
          }
        }
      ),
    );
  }
```

**For more info and a performance tips visit**

[Flutter Widget of the Week - FutureBuilder](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ek8ZPdWj4Qo)

[FutureBuilder Docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)